# Only slideUp the deleted message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a PM system and added the delete-message feature. I've got a form which checks for the message_id and message_title. The form posts to delete_message.php page which contains the query to delete the message. This has been done via Javascript as I dont want the page to refresh.

I've got two functions for this:

```
function deleteMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "message/delete_message.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#delMsgForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishDeleteMessage(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
    });
}

function finishDeleteMessage( data , textStatus ,jqXHR ) {
    $(".inboxMessage").slideUp('slow');
}
```

Currently when I click on the delete button (image of a trashcan) it deletes the message without reloading the page, as a finishing touch, it slidesUp the divclass (inboxMessage) the message is in. Since I tell it to slide up this class, it slides up every message. This is my piece of code containing the classes and the form:

```
<div class="inboxMessage">
<div class="inboxMessageImg NoNewMsg"></div>
<div class="inboxMessageHeader">
<a id="ajax" class="inboxMessageLink" onclick="showMessage('.$row['message_id'].')">'.$row['message_title'].'</a>
<p class="inboxMessageStatus Read">'.$inboxMessageStatus_Read.'</p>
</div>
<div class="inboxMessageDescription">'.$inboxMessageDescription.'</div>
<div class="inboxMessageActions">
<form id="delMsgForm" name="delMsgForm" action="message/delete_message.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="msgTitle" value="'.$row['message_title'].'" name="message_title">
<input type="hidden" id="msgID" value="'.$row['message_id'].'" name="message_id">
</form>
<input type="submit" id="ajax" value="" name="deleteMessageButton" class="deleteMessageIcon" onclick="deleteMessage()">
</div>
</div>
```

What I want it to do is to slideUp only the message which has just been deleted by the user. I know this has to be done by telling javascript to only slideUp the deleted message which contains the message_id and/or message_title.

I've tried several things, but no love whatsoever. I'm also not that familiar with javascript/ajax. Any help would be highly appreciate.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where do you call deleteMessage from? indirect the function call through another function which knows the parent of your "trash can", and can call slide up on that specific one.

```
function deleteMessage (element) {
    //element will be clicked button
    var container = $(element).closest("div.inboxMessage"),
        //container div including the trashcan
    $.ajax({
        url: "message/delete_message.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#delMsgForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   
            finishDeleteMessage(container); 
        }
    });        
});
```

and this will be your button

```
<input type="submit" id="ajax" value="" name="deleteMessageButton" class="deleteMessageIcon" onclick="deleteMessage(this)">
```

Comment: I feel really stupid sayin' this but i dunno what you're talking about. Once again, I'm just a beginner. The trashcan is not a div, its the submit button: <input type="submit" id="ajax" value="" name="deleteMessageButton" class="deleteMessageIcon" onclick="deleteMessage()">

Comment: No worries. the div with class inboxMessage is a repeated one, right? and your goal is to slide up the "deleted" one. the way to do that, is to have some sort of access to the element which triggers the delete action. I'm gonna modify my answer to match your html page

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you've got more divs with class `inboxMessage`. Since you're adding this code:

```
 $(".inboxMessage").slideUp('slow');
```

.. all divs with that class will remove. If you want just one div to remove, give it a unique ID or data-attribute and hide it that way.

For example: add the message-id to the div..

```
<div class="inboxMessage" id="(message_id)">
```

..and use..

```
 $(".inboxMessage#message_id").slideUp('slow');
```

.. to slide up the right div.

---

Edit:

Add your message ID to the div and to the function `deleteMessage()`, so it will be `deleteMessage(message_id)`.

```
function deleteMessage(message_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "message/delete_message.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#delMsgForm").serialize(),
        success: function(){   finishDeleteMessage(message_id); }
    });
}

function finishDeleteMessage(message_id) {
    $(".inboxMessage#"+message_id).slideUp('slow');
}
```

Comment: Cheers for your input. The inboxMessage div is now receiving the correct message id. However,  $(".inboxMessage#message_id").slideUp('slow'); does not work

Comment: No, #message_id should be replaced by the ID you're removing. You know how to do that? (You can take it from the `data`-parameter of your function)

Comment: Oh god, no I dont.. :(